# Using C-like API in OOP

Tags: c++, api, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I am writing some classes in C++ to act as a personal small library and I encountered a problem.

Some of my objects make us of third-party libraries written in magnificent C style.
That means those libraries have functions like `apiInit()` and `apiCleanup()`, where the former must be called before any of the actual api functions and the latter must be called when you are not going to use them anymore.

What I want is to provide the classes that need a library with an access point to its functions ensuring `apiInit()` is called when the first needing class is created, or at least before any api function is used, and `apiCleanup()` is called when the last instance that uses the api is destroyed.

Keep in mind there are more than one class that makes use of a single library.

I could come with two solutions:

First, the obvious one, make the provider a singleton:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class ContextProvider {

  ContextProvider() {
    cout << "Initializing API" << endl;
  }

  ContextProvider(ContextProvider const& rhs) = delete;
  ContextProvider& operator=(ContextProvider const& rhs) = delete;

public:

  ~ContextProvider() {
    cout << "Cleaning API" << endl;
  }

  static ContextProvider& getInstance() {
    static ContextProvider instance;
    return instance;
  }

  void useContext() {
    cout << "Using API" << endl;
  }
};


class ContextUser1 {


public:

  ContextUser1() {

  }

  void doSomething() {
    ContextProvider::getInstance().useContext();
  }
};


class ContextUser2 {

public:

  ContextUser2() {

  }

  void doSomethingElse() {
    ContextProvider::getInstance().useContext();
  }
};
```

The other one would be to keep a counter of context users, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class ContextProvider {
  static unsigned int userCounter;

public:

  ContextProvider() {
    if (userCounter == 0)
      cout << "Initializing API" << endl;

    ++userCounter;
  }

  ~ContextProvider() {
    --userCounter;

    if (userCounter == 0)
      cout << "Cleaning API" << endl;
  }

  void useContext() {
    cout << "Using API" << endl;
  }
};

unsigned int ContextProvider::userCounter = 0;


class ContextUser1 {
  ContextProvider cp;

public:

  ContextUser1() {
    cp = ContextProvider();
  }

  void doSomething() {
    cp.useContext();
  }
};


class ContextUser2 {
  ContextProvider cp;

public:

  ContextUser2() {
    cp = ContextProvider();
  }

  void doSomethingElse() {
    cp.useContext();
  }
};


int main() {
  ContextUser1 cu11, cu12, cu13;
  ContextUser2 cu21, cu22;

  cu11.doSomething();
  cu12.doSomething();
  cu21.doSomethingElse();
  cu22.doSomethingElse();
  cu13.doSomething();
}
```

Both, when executed with the following `main()`

```
int main() {
  ContextUser1 cu11, cu12, cu13;
  ContextUser2 cu21, cu22;

  cu11.doSomething();
  cu12.doSomething();
  cu21.doSomethingElse();
  cu22.doSomethingElse();
  cu13.doSomething();
}
```

yeld the expected result, that is:

```
Initializing API
Using API
Using API
Using API
Using API
Using API
Cleaning API
```

Now the obvious question is, **which one is better, or which one should I use?**

For example, some things that come to mind are...

Singleton method:

- Advantages:

  - No need to store any counter.
  - No need to store any instance.
- Disadvantages:

  - Syntaxis gets weird (`ContextProvider::getInstance().use()`).
  - It is a singleton, with all it's flaws.

Counter method:

- Advantages:

  - The usage is straightfowrard.
  - The syntaxis is nice and clear (`cp.use()`).
- Disadvantages:

  - Has to keep a counter of the number of users.
  - User classes have to store an instance of the ContextProvider class.

I mainly ask this question because I don't know which of these advantages/disadvantages weight more, if there are things I didn't account for, or maybe there is an obvious third method I couldn't come up with that is inherently better than those two, or, who knows.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You might be looking for so-called ["nifty counters"](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Nifty_Counter). It's a trick the standard library uses to make sure `std::cout` et al are initialized and available before first use.

Comment: How expensive is restarting the API? How often will objects of the API *all* be destroyed only to have new ones created soon after?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Isn't that exacly what I am doing in the second example?

Comment: @rpattiso Yeah I thought about this. I don't know how expensive it is, but I am thinking about APIs like GLFW or WinSock, so that situation should not happen, or at least very sporadicly.

Comment: More or less, except that nifty counters don't require one to explicitly mention `ContextProvider`. It happens simply by means of including the header that defines the library classes. I must admit I haven't looked at your code closely before posting the comment - just read the first paragraph and thought it matched nifty counter idiom.

Comment: Maybe [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate for this.

Comment: @rpattiso  This is nowhere close to being ready for code review.  Code Review reviews working code with a real purpose.  It's not the place to discuss hypothetical code.

Comment: @Hydn Regarding Winsock, that´s a not-problem. You can call WSAStartup multiple times, and as many calls to WSACleanup

Comment: @deviantfan Fair, but you still have to time WSACleanup so that all objects using Winsock have died. Plus some libraries return error on init() if they are already initialized.

Comment: @Hydn `but you still have to time WSACleanup so that all objects using Winsock have died` Not sure about that. If I remember correctly, it has some counter too, internally, and does nothing until the last call except for decreasing the counter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use your second approach, with the following modifications:

```
class ContextUser1 {
  std::shared_ptr<ContextProvider> cp;

public:

  ContextUser1(const std::shared_ptr<ContextProvider>& cp)
      : cp(cp) {
  }

  void doSomething() {
      cp->useContext();
  }
};
```

Making the dependency explicit makes your code better in terms of being testable. Also, using `shared_ptr` takes care of counting, so you don't even need to do this yourself.